# Button = Website Link in AutoIT

Tags: user-interface, autoit

I have made a button in AutoIT for this program we are making for work we will call it $okmystery and I want $okmystery to like to my company website. Here is a snippet of the code I have so far:

```
Dim $msg
GUISetState()
    While 1
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                ExitLoop
            Case $msg = $okbutton
                ; Minimize Current Window
                WinSetState( $WINTITLE, "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
                While Not BitAND(WinGetState($WINTITLE, ""), 16)
                    sleep( 250 )
                WEnd

                ; Take Screen Shots and Logs
                ScreenShotAndLogs()

                ; Compress Artifacts
                If FileExists( $ZIPFILEPATH ) Then FileDelete( $ZIPFILEPATH )
                _Zip_Create( $ZIPFILEPATH )
                _Zip_AddFolderContents( $ZIPFILEPATH, $OUTPUTROOT )
                DeleteOriginals()

                ; Restore main window
                WinSetState( $WINTITLE, "", @SW_RESTORE)
            ;------------ Screen Shot
            Case $msg = $okshot
                ; Minimize Current Window
                WinSetState( $WINTITLE, "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
                While Not BitAND(WinGetState($WINTITLE, ""), 16)
                    sleep( 250 )
                WEnd

                ScreenShot()

                ; Restore main window
                WinSetState( $WINTITLE, "", @SW_RESTORE)
                ;----------------------------------
            $okmystery = ShellExecute ("basic")
                Run("Http://www.IT-Networks.org")

            Case Default
                ; Do Nothing
        EndSelect
    WEnd
Exit( 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change the "$okmystery" case statement to match the other case statements (if those are all working like they're supposed to).

You can then try to `ShellExecute()` the url.

```
Case $msg = $okmystery
  ShellExecute("Http://www.IT-Networks.org")
```

---

Here's a working example of a GUI with a button that opens your company website in your default web browser:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

Global $Button_1, $msg

GUICreate("Test GUI Button")
$okmystery = GUICtrlCreateButton("okmystery Button", 10, 30, 100)

GUISetState()

While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ExitLoop
        Case $msg = $okmystery
            ShellExecute("Http://www.IT-Networks.org")
    EndSelect
WEnd
```